# error with a bool function "Control reaches end of non-void function"

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors, boolean

i looked at other related questions but couldnt quite make sense of it
i am writing a console project for my c++ class using xcode.

the goal of the program is to evaluate if a number is prime or not.
( i realize the logic of my function is off, its just a working idea for now)
can someone tell me what im doing wrong? I'm following the class notes exactly except for the math part which is of my own devising..

```
// Assignment 6 - Prime Number
// 9-28-17

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

bool primeCheck(int); //function prototype

int main ()
{
int num;       // declares number for input

cout << "Enter an integer to see if it is prime. ";
cin  >> num;

while (num < 1)    // validation loop
{
cout << "Invalid. Enter an integer. ";
cin  >> num;
}

if (primeCheck(num))
    cout << num << " is not prime" << endl;
else
    cout << num << " is prime" << endl;

    return 0;
}


bool primeCheck(int val)  // function to check for primality
 {
    bool status;

    if ((val %2 != 0) || (val %3 != 0) || (val %5 != 0 ) 
       || (val %7 != 0) || ((sqrt(val)) != 0))
    status = false;
    else
    status = false;
 }
```

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please provide the relevant code. Welcome to SO.

Comment: You don't have a `return` in one branch? Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to *guess* more. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please [provide](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46483721/edit) the code as code, not as images.

Comment: sorry everyone, ill take the tour and format questions propoerly in the future. I plan to be on here quite a bit.

Comment: indentation is eye-gauging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not returned anything from primeCheck. Simply assigning your result to status is not enough, you need to write `return status` at the end of the function so that if knows exactly what it's supposed to be returning to whatever calls primeCheck.

```
bool primeCheck(int val)
{
    bool status;

    if (val %2 != 0 || val %3 != 0 || val %5 !=0 || (val %7 != 0 && (sqrt(val)) != 0))
        status = false;
    else 
        status = false;

    return status;
 }
```

Also I think you may have made a mistake, and there are some things that you can do to improve it anyway.

1. All your branches (the `if` and the `else`) assign `false` to `status`. presumably the first branch (when the `if` is `true`) should assign `true` to status?
2. Typically it's good practice to always use curly brackets with `if` and `else` statements. This makes it clear what code belongs to the branch in question:

   ```
   if ( foo )
       doSomething();
       doSomethingElse();
   ```

   would actually be interpreted by the compiler as:

   ```
   if ( foo ){
       doSomething();
   }
   doSomethingElse();
   ```
3. You don't actually need to declare `bool status` or assign `true` or `false` to it. You can simply return your result directly. Although this just is a matter of style for some people.

With that in mind, here is an improved version of you function:

```
bool primeCheck(int val)
{
    if (val %2 != 0 || val %3 != 0 || val %5 !=0 || (val %7 != 0 && (sqrt(val)) != 0)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You don't even need the `if`, you can just do `return (val %2 != 0 || val %3 != 0 || val %5 !=0 || (val %7 != 0 && (sqrt(val)) != 0));`

Comment: The actual calculation is rather suspect too. I doubt OP wants `val %7 != 0 && (sqrt(val)) != 0` because that's `(bool logical_and double) not_equal 0`